# At what time step the microstructure noise start to kick in?

Tags: high-frequency, market-microstructure

When looking for papers on-line I often find things designed specifically to deal with micro-structure noise. I spent some time trying to understand / implement / test them for results that vary widely. I would be interested to know at below which timestep this micro-structure noise really starts to kick-in. Or conversely at above which timestep I can start to ignore these papers.

In [Market Microstructure in Practice (Lehalle Laruelle Eds)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814566160) the chronology of market speed start at 2MHz in the 70s and ends at 3.6Ghz at the starts of 2018. The SEC consulted market participants in 2010 about microstructure well after the GHz step that happened in the 00's. Does that mean that anything above the ms, s or minute is free from micro-structure noise ? (Or just that regulators were a bit slow on that concept ?)

Comment: By definition the microstructure has to do with the time between two successive trades, which can be measured. Figures like 2 MHz and so on sound like CPU clock frequencies which is a completely different concept, I am not sure of its relevance.

Comment: Hertz is a frequency.... so a number of operation per second, that easily give a timestep between operation. 2Mhz = up to 2.000.000 operations per seconds => 1/2.000.000 seconds between operations.

Comment: BtW it usually has to do with microprice such as WAP that might be defined without trades ... so not sure we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: the number of trade per day (or per hour, or per minute, or per second) can be expressed in Hz @noob2 and it is a convenient concept since Shannon's law stands for retrieving information from ticking updates.

Answer (score 4):

##### A 5-minute sampling frequency is a popular choice when avoiding the adverse effects of microstructure noise:

When dealing with eg. estimation of intraday volatility estimates **there is a wide consensus that sampling at a 5-minute frequency** will keep the bias induced by the microstructure noise to a minimum and still contain the added information inherent in high-frequency data.

The choice of a 5-minute frequency can be observed in the article of [Hansen, P. R., & Lunde, A. (2006)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/073500106000000071?casa_token=bzodLQjGdgoAAAAA:No1rjJX4G4naTbY-i-0COioOhnFxMkFQ4z7PYTYbDndOD8g0dH0S53dRbRRDxxrNdZu7Nv_zXCHTwZo) that studies the market microstructure noise in high-frequency data and analyze its implications for the realized variance ($RV_t=\sum_{i=1}^n r_{i,t}^2$)*** under a general specification for the noise. They specifically construct *volatility signature plots* — by plotting frequency on the x-axis and realized variance on the y-axis — and observe for which frequency $RV_t$ stabilises (*see Figure 1*). **Here, they find that the bias induced by microstructure noise is not present at a 5-minute sampling frequency for the realized variance estimator**.

In conclusion, you can ignore the effects of microstructure noise in your data (*and the papers dealing with this matter*) when sparse sampling at a 5-minute frequency for most asset-classes.

---

While it might not be intraday volatility estimation you are dealing with, **you can use the above as a rule of thumb for when microstructure noise becomes prominent in the data.**

*** *The realized variance estimator is not robust in the presence of microstructure noise.*

Answer (score 2):

**Not sure that I will go for a 5 min scale for any stocks; it really depends on the liquidity** of the stock. For some 15 minutes is better, and for other 1h or 1:30 hours.

Of course it is easy to state this since "liquidity" is not well defined, and could be even be defined a circular way: this time scale is the one at which you "recover" liquidity. It is probably at this rhythm that one should take strategic trading decisions (i.e. trade scheduling) and keep the tactical ones (cross the bid-ask spread or not, wait further away in the book, etc) inside these natural time intervals.

**In practice** (to paraphrase the title of this "excellent" book... by the way, [there is a second edition](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/10739)), I would implement three estimators of volatility

- the naive one
- the German-Klass (the minimum variance estimator using a polynomial formula of the OHLC)
- a microstructure one (you can go for the [Uncertainty zones model](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.451.9183&rep=rep1&type=pdf) of Rosenbaum et al. or for the [Multiscale one](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eyacine/twoscales.pdf) of Zhang, Mykland and Ait Shalia).

And you compare them on each stock until you find a time scale at while they give similar results. That is not very complicated to code an automated scan of few reasonable scales and run it on your whole universe; you will **end up with the correct time scale for each instrument**. You can update this every year (or when the tick of the stock changes). I would moreover monitor [Rosenbaum's $\eta$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6325.pdf) to check the scale when it changes too much.

Comment: My understanding is that,  when the literature talks about a realized variance estimator, they tend to not talk about an underlying model for the returns themselves. For example, suppose one had $r_{(t,t+1)} = \beta r_{(t-1,t)} + x_{(t-1,t)} + \epsilon_{(t,t+1)}$ where $r_{(t-1,t)}$ denotes the return from $(t-1)$ to $t$ and $\epsilon_{(t,t+1)}$ has some variance, $\sigma^2$.  Then, this variance, $\sigma^2$, cannot be viewed as the realized volatility right because it is part of an underlying model for the returns ? Is that right ? Thanks.

Comment: Note that in the above, I am describing a return model for the 1 minute returns but I could have written a similar one for 2 minute returns or 5 minute returns  or 10 minute returns etc, in which case, the $\sigma^2$ would be the variance of the respective horizon return.

Comment: Be aware that the 5-minute sampling frequency is a rule of thumb (or a popular choice), and not a strict rule to follow (*In my article above, they also specify 20-min as an even safer sampling choice*). Yes, the choice of sampling frequency is dependent on the "liquidity" of the asset and one should do his own analysis to determine when the volatility estimators (RV and eg. a noise-robust estimator, or as your example above) stabilize around a frequency (a lá *volatility signature plot*).  However, for  "liquid" assets, a 5-minute sampling frequency is a fine rule of thumb [1/2]

Comment: since it still contains the informational gain inherent in high-frequency data while keeping microstructure noise at a minimum (even the Zhang, Mykland paper in your answer, notes that 5-minute frequency is a literature preferred choice). Sampling at a frequency of 1-hour or lower, will lose you much of the " high-frequency performance" (especially if you're measuring between market open and close) and one should ask himself, whether the increased complexity of cleaning and handling intraday data is worth it, if it only gives marginally better results than daily frequencies. :-) [2/2]

Comment: @lehalle: thank you for the method to estimate a timescale and references. Your book  make a good candidate for a Christmas present to myself this year. It was my understanding that for volatility the main effect was coming from rounding micro prices  to ticks. Could simulating a GBM with a given $\sigma$ and a tick would allow to estimate how much noise affect the RV as a function of these parameters ? Or am I oversimplifying the problem ? Also, reading between the lines, I understand that sampling trough contsant volume traded might be another solution.

Comment: @markleeds "realised variance" refers to the "naive estimator", nothing to do with the underlying model. It is really the variance of the empirical returns. If you have suspicion of mean-reversion (that is far from stupid for intraday returns), the "realised variance" will not take this assumption into account. You can of course build an estimator of the $\sigma^2$ in your VAR(1) model, but it will not be the "realised variance of the returns".

Comment: @Pleb it depends what you want to do with your estimate of the volatility. There is never *one best estimate,ator*, there is the *adequate estimator for one specific usage*. Disentangling the microstructure noise (call it "Rosenbaum's $\eta$) and the volatility of the underlying makes sense, but only if you want to reuse them (for intraday trading or risk management).

Comment: @lcrmorin you will need more that a GBM and a tick, Mathieu R's model with $\eta$ (see any of his "uncertainty zones" papers) is probably the one that is closest to what you want.

Comment: @lehalle: I know see why. GBM will give constant eta as random walks don’t have a continuation/alternation structure. So my interpretation might have been too simple. Noise doesn’t only come from rounding to tick but also from some changing local autocorrelation.

Comment: @Lehalle: Thanks for the clarification on the realized variance. i figured that was it but I wanted to confirm that the concept doesn't apply to frameworks where one is building intraday models for the returns. All the best.